# How do you import DCAppAttestService?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Objective-C, how do I include the Framework containing DCAppAttestService so that I can do this:

`DCAppAttestService *attestService = [[DCAppAttestService alloc] init];`

Comment: It's part of [`DeviceCheck`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck?language=objc) so, `#import <DeviceCheck.h>` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Objective-C `.m` file, add the following import:

```
#import <DeviceCheck/DCAppAttestService.h>
```

Add the framework `DeviceCheck.framework` under *Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content* in the *General* tab of your target.

Note however that, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/establishing_your_app_s_integrity?language=objc), you should use the `DCAppAttestService.sharedService` singleton instead of creating your own.